# How are patterns for eye diagrams sliced?

Tags: eye-diagram

I am reading articles about eye diagrams (for example, [Anatomy of an Eye Diagram](https://www.montana.edu/aolson/eele445/homework_labs/Tektronix_eyediagram.pdf).) Everywhere in the description of the diagram formation method they talk about multiple overlay of patterns, about 001, 010, 100, 011, 110 and so on.

It is not clear how the beginning of the pattern is determined.

Is it by crossing a certain edge cutoff?  If so, then there would be a node on the left side of the eye diagram - a point whare all the patterns intersect and the left side itself would be as thin as possible while the right eye diagram would be “scattered” due to jitter. It is, however, common for eye diagrams to be nearly symmetrical.

[image]

(Image source: [SciPy Cookbook - Eye Diagram](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/EyeDiagram.html))

In the center of the bit?

In the center of the bit there is emptiness, there is nothing to grab onto. It would be possible to cling to the middle between the rising and falling edge, but how then to hang pattern 110, which has only one front (and in general, any pattern with an odd number of fronts.)

How are patterns for eye diagrams sliced?

Comment: It's not clear where you are having your trouble understanding eye patterns. Maybe you are expecting them to represent something that they were not designed to represent? Emptiness is really good. Smudging can be acceptable but, if it begins to make the empty centre um, filled then it's bad.

Comment: Ideally, the center of that "empty" region is where you want to sample the incoming bit/data stream.  What's shown in your picture is a very good eye diagram.

Comment: Generally, the timing *difference* across *many* leading and trailing edges is evaluated (to answer your query about leading and trailing edge display). The same type of functionality measures time and amplitude differences over several hundred or thousand points of many symbols to generate a complete eye diagram.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it by crossing a certain edge cutoff? If so, then there would be a node on the left side of the eye diagram - a point whare all the patterns intersect and the left side itself would be as thin as possible while the right eye diagram would be “scattered” due to jitter. It is, however, common for eye diagrams to be nearly symmetrical.

If this is being done on an oscilloscope, you're limited by the triggering technology of the scope.

25 years ago, the scopes that could do this function would only trigger on a clock signal, applied to a different input of the scope than the sampled signal. Further, the minimum delay from the trigger event to the sample was on the order of 20 ns (IIRC). So the jitter on the two sides of the eye was nearly equal simply because there was a substantial delay between the trigger event and the actual data samples being taken.

Now there are various technologies at play.

A 100 GSa/s real-time scope could produce the effect you are expecting if you were to simply trigger on the data edge. But these scopes also typically offer DSP features that produce results similar to the PLL described in glen_geek's answer. This allows them to (like a PLL) track low frequency timing wander and give a measure of jitter more comparable to what the receiver would see in the real system.

Today's equivalent-time sampling scopes still have long delays from the trigger event to the sample instant. But they also have timing correction features and PLL simulation to (in principle) eliminate the jitter introduced by the trigger circuit and show you only the actual jitter in the signal relative to ideal timing.

So unless you deliberately choose the real-time scope and data-edge triggering without timing correction (which is against the standard methods for eye diagram measurements) you will see equal jitter on the two sides of the eye, not one "perfect" edge and one jittered edge.

Side note: If I recall correctly, USB (at certain data rates) does have a specification for pulse width jitter, which would be correctly measured with data edge timing --- and the eye diagram in that measurement should in fact have no jitter on the leading edge and all jitter measured on the trailing edge.

Answer (score 1):

[image: annotated OP's eye diagram]

This image has thousands of bits overlaid as a kind of histogram where colour corresponds to repeated passes over the same "pixel". The colour histogram scale is shown to the right.

The horizontal trigger is very likely from the receiving end's clock chain, derived from a phase-locked-loop.

You've described a triggering system common to oscilloscopes where the trigger is referenced to a particular intersection on its displayed X/Y grid.
This eye-diagram is somewhat different, since its horizontal scale is referenced to the clock derived from phase-locked loop. It is apparent that one clock cycle covers six divisions...however this bit-clock is not displayed, so you cannot see how much it jitters. What *is displayed* is noisy data bits. Their amplitude varies somewhat more than 1.5 divisions, whereas their mid-bit zero crossing varies about 1.5 divisions.

Answer (score 0):

Eye pattern is useful for signal quality checking if

- the data pulses have constant transmission rate
- the actual data is coded to the voltage of the pulse and there's only few possible voltage levels (your example has 2 levels)

The eye pattern has a high and wide, well open eye if there's always good changes to decide which one of the possible voltage levels was sent (1 or 0 in your example)

The data signal is not sliced. The oscilloscope is triggered by a timer so that during each sweep the midpoint of the data pulse is in the middle of the screen. No need to show every data pulse. There only must be a pulse so often that a good image is drawn.

The data sequence is random or pseudo-random so that all possible data pulse voltage levels occur frequently enough. As said in a comment, also a variety of pulse sequences is a must for example to reveal the effect of the spreading of the pulses.

The eye pattern can become bad (=eye closed) for the next reasons:

- the transmission channel causes ringing or echoes or other filtering effects so that adjacent pulses spread over each other
- there's non-linearity which distorts voltage levels
- there's noise
- the timing extraction is bad in the receiver or the transmitter has jitter (=the transmission rate swings). In both cases the triggering of the oscilloscope happens in wrong times.

So, the eye pattern reveals qualitatively the total combined effect of noise, poor timing and pulse form distortions. In the receiver poor timing can be caused by noise, pulse form distortions or poor design of the timing extractor.

Comment: Not just "all possible data pulse voltage levels", but also all possible combinations of 0's and 1's that could be expected.  For example, the channel performance, and hence the eye may be different for a bit sequence of 01010101... and 000100010001...